# How to detect click outside window

Tags: javascript, yui

I have a customized dropdown in html coded in "ul" and "li",  I show options when a user clicks on the head of "ul" I would like to hide these elements when the user clicks outside the menu area.

Is something like this possible with javascript/YUI not Jquery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not a YUI guy, so I suspect this could be written a bit better, but I have tested it and it works.

Hide the dropdown anytime the document is clicked:

```
Y.one(document).on("click", function(){
    Y.one("#menu").hide(); 
});
```

Prevent clicks on the `ul` from propagating to the `document`:

```
Y.one("#menu").on("click", function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();    
});
```

If the visitor clicks anywhere, the click will bubble up to the `document`, and hide the menu. If they click on the menu, the event will be prevented from bubbling up to the `document`, and as such the menu will not be hidden.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nHnZT/

Comment: @ajax333221 No, the example above (though similar to jQuery) is YUI.

Comment: Many thanks Jonathan, it works for me. for using this line of code we need to add <script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.5.1/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>.

Answer (score 2):

`use('event-outside')` adds support for "outside" events.  See the user guide for details: http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/event/outside.html